# Search and replace text using Regex in IntelliJ

Tags: regex, scala, intellij-idea

I am using the latest version of the IntelliJ Idea 2017.1

In my project I have many calls to this function

foo.bar(x)

I want to search and replace this to x.toFoo

The problem is that X can be anything. it can be any variable, it can be a long function call. So we don't really know the pattern for x.

I tried this regex

`foo.bar(\S+)` but this doesn't work as it selects many other things.

I also tried `foo.bar(\()(.*)(\))` this seems to select the right thing. but at the time of replacing. how do I remember to capture whatever was there in .*?

Example

```
foo.bar(myobj.copy(myid = hisId))
```

this should become

```
myobj.copy(myid = hisId).toFoo
```

another example can be

```
foo.bar(List(1, 2, 3))

List(1, 2, 3).toFoo
```

Comment: Could `x` have nested parenthesis?

Comment: It can be any valid scala expression. so yes, it can have nested parenthesis.

Comment: Structural Search in Intellij works for Java and Groovy, but unfortunately not in Scala. deleted my answer therefore.

Answer (score 1):

Since your string can have nested parenthesis, I would have suggested using recursion:

```
foo\.bar(\(([^()]|(?1))*\))
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/VOMo3U/1)

However IntelliJ doesn't support that (*actually haven't seen any IDE supporting recursion*).

So instead you can use:

```
foo\.bar[^\(]*(\(.*\))[^\)]*?
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/Ng3yaz/1)

Which given this:

```
foo.bar()
foo.bar(1, 2, 3)
foo.bar(1, (2 + (3 + 4)), 5)
```

*You didn't give any example, so I just made some containing nested parenthesis.*

Results in:

```
().toFoo
(1, 2, 3).toFoo
(1, (2 + (3 + 4)), 5).toFoo
```

Comment: gave example. I tried `foo\.bar[^\(]*(\(.*\))[^\)]*?` but it finds nothing.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Could you give some more descriptive examples than `foo.bar(x)` ?

Comment: Is everything on a single line? If so wouldn't `foo\.bar\((.*)\)` be enough?